# How to refresh vector tile layer after setting declutter in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: vector-tiles, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers version 6. I want to change the declutter of a vector tile layer by using `vecTileLayer.set('decluter',false)`.

After changing declutter of layer with the `set` method of `vecTileLayer`, My map is not updated and nothing changes.

I also used `vecTileLayer.getSource().refresh()` to refresh layer after setting declutter, but nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
layer.set('declutter',!layer.get('declutter'));
layer.getSource().refresh()
```

How should I change `declutter` of a vector tile layer and see updates on the map?

Comment: Changing constructor options using `set()` is unlikely to have any effect, only those with bespoke methods such as `setSource()`, `setStyle()`, `setVisible()`, etc. would work.  It would be easier to create and add two layers with identical options except for declutter and visible and toggle their visibility using `layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible()).`

Comment: Thank you but it seems it is not a standard way!

Comment: There is no standard way.  If it was intended to updateable there would be a setDeclutter() method.

Comment: @Mike It seems [this answer](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11634#issuecomment-706074253) is more standard!

Comment: Yes, it works but using an internal value not documented in the API isn't good practice and might not work in feature releases.  Adding a documented setDeclutter method (for both Vector and VectorTile layers) would be safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11634), on the GitHub repo of OpenLayers. [M393](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11634#issuecomment-706074253) Answered me a way of changing declutter and it worked truly.

I used this code and it worked truly.

```
layer.declutter_ = !layer.declutter_;
let source = layer.getSource();
source.refresh()
```

Also, [M393](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11634#issuecomment-706074253) said, `A PR adding the missing setDeclutter(declutter) method with the above code might make sense, unless this causes some problem which I didn't run into when I tried this ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It's refreshing for me. I don't know it's good for your case or not. (zoom filtering just extra.)

```
    var lyrSource = new VectorTileSource({
        cacheSize: 1,
        format: new MVT(),
        url: 'http://localhost:9080/maps/mapname/:layer/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf',
    });

    var layer = new VectorTileLayer({
        preload: 0,
        declutter: true,
        title: 'Layer', //optional
        visible: true,  //optional
        source: lyrSource,
        minZoom: 10, //optional
        style: styleFunction
    });

    function refresh() {
        var zoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom(); //optional
        console.log("zoom: " + zoomLevel)  //optional
        if (zoomLevel > 12) {  //optional
            console.log('Time is running: '+ new Date())
            lyrSource.tileCache.expireCache({});
            lyrSource.tileCache.clear();
            lyrSource.refresh();
        } //optional

    }

    setInterval(refresh, 5000)
```

Comment: Thanks,but I used this code 
`layer.set('declutter',!layer.get('declutter'));let source = layer.getSource(); source.tileCache.expireCache({});source.tileCache.clear();source.refresh()`. 
it's not working.